# JQuery Chrome Extension, unable to change css attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple chrome extension that I use on one URL to change the layout of a page very slightly (color, position etc)

I'm trying to do the same on a new URL. The code I'm using for both is the same and it works fine on one URL but not another.

This is the failing code. I've replaced the actual URL with `SITE` in this post.

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.toLowerCase().indexOf('SITE') >= 0) {   
    console.log ('Amending CSS');

    $('.main-container').css({"background":"red"});

}
```

The element I'm trying to change is:
`<clr-main-container _ngcontent-c0="" class="main-container">`

Checking my console I see 'Amending CSS' but nothing appears to have changed.

The URL is accessed via HTTPS and is a firewall, so I'm not sure if there is a way they could block changes or not.

Any one any ideas on this thanks :)

Comment: use like $('.main-container').css("background","red");

Comment: Have you checked the element in devtools to see if the CSS rule is being applied? Does the element exist in the DOM when your code runs?

Comment: @DanielASathishKumar that's logically identical. If the OPs original doesn't work, then that won't have any effect either

Comment: maybe an `!important` rule was declared?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Yeah, you are correct

Comment: Use should use the property as background-color instead background in either way

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  When I logged out of the firewall the background turned red.
So it is applying something.. It looks like a direct style code on the element is overriding the css. Is there anyway to change that ?

Comment: @Tom probably, but it depends on what rules are overriding your setting, and where they are applied. Can you add a working example containing all relevant HTML, CSS and JS code to the question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - the working example is exactly the same but targeting a different class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying the same and it's working for snippet website check:

```js
$(function(){
  var url = window.location.href;
  console.log(url);
  if (url.toLowerCase().indexOf('stacksnippets') >= 0) { 
    console.log ('Amending CSS');
    $('body').css({"background":"red"});
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If the previous code didn't work with this might be due to a `css` on the same element with higher priority `!important`

check this:

```js
$(function(){
  var url = window.location.href;
  console.log(url);
  if (url.toLowerCase().indexOf('stacksnippets') >= 0) { 
    console.log ('Amending CSS');
    $('body').addClass("red_bg");;
  }
});
```

```css
.red_bg
{
background:red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> [image: Upvote if you like it]

Comment: Thanks this has helped me sort it.

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to wrap your code in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// your code
});
```

This will wait for the page to be ready before it runs the code, hopefully ensuring the element is on the page.

May i also recommend the chrome extension, Stylebot.  It allows you to apply custom CSS to any website, and it will remember it for future visits.

Comment: Thanks - sorry I should have said the while code is wrapped in this.